# Deriving the variance of an OLS estimator

Tags: probability, least-squares

I am trying to understand what I am misunderstanding when computing the variance of the OLS estimator.

Using the formula for the variance:

V($\hat\beta$) = E($\hat\beta$$\hat\beta^T$) - E($\hat\beta$)^2
= E($\hat\beta$$\hat\beta^T$) - $\beta$^2.

But the first term here gives me the variance I expect which is
$\sigma^2(X^TX)^-1$ and im not sure why I have the extra term

Comment: Hi: If you want to use that type of expression, you need to use it on  zero mean random variables. So, define $\hat{\beta} - \beta = (X^{\prime}X)^{-1} X^{\prime} u$ where $u$ is the residual. Next, calculate $E(\hat{\beta} - \beta)(\hat{\beta} - \beta)^{\prime}$.

Comment: This formula just follows from the definition of the variance, does it not ?@markleeds

Comment: No, the formula here is $\operatorname{Var}(\hat\beta)=E(\hat\beta\hat\beta^T)-E(\hat\beta)E(\hat\beta)^T$. But there are easier ways of finding the covariance matrix of $\hat\beta$.

Comment: @John Smith: That's the formula but $\hat{\beta}$ is an estimate that is really  $(X^\prime X)^{-1} X^{\prime} y $ WHICH ARE KNOWN so it's better to use them. This is what the formula I wrote does.  Also, $E(\hat{\beta})$ does equal $\beta$ but that's not helpful because $\beta$ is an unknown parameter.

Comment: If you calculate the expectation: $E(\hat{\beta} - \beta)(\hat{\beta} - \beta)^{\prime}$ by  putting in the expression I wrote for $(\hat{\beta} - \beta)$, you will get $\sigma^2 (X^{\prime} X)^{-1}$.